# Receiving 502 bad gateway when deploying WordPress using Cloud Init on Azure VMSS

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx, cloud-init

Hello I am trying to deploy a WordPress instance to a VM Scale Set on Azure with an Application Gateway using Terraform and a Cloud init.

Currently I have come to the conclusion that the issue is a result of how the 'wordpress.conf' and  'wp-config.php' files are being mounted and not due to infrastructure related configurations since when the commands are limited to only starting nginx the public ip returns the 'Welcome to nginx' message on the expected port 80.

Here is the cloud init file currently being used

```
    #cloud-config
    package_upgrade: true
    packages:
      - nginx
      - php-curl
      - php-gd
      - php-intl
      - php-mbstring
      - php-soap
      - php-xml
      - php-xmlrpc
      - php-zip
      - php-fpm
      - php-mysql
      - nfs-common

    write_files:
    - path: /tmp/wp-config.php
      content: |
          <?php
          define('DB_NAME', 'wordpressdb');
          define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
          define('DB_PASSWORD', 'w0rdpr3ss@p4ss');
          define('DB_HOST', '${database_fqdn}');
          $table_prefix = 'wp_';
          if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
            define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
          }
          require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
          ?>


    - path: /tmp/wordpress.conf
      content: |
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name _;
            root /data/nfs/wordpress;

            index index.html index.htm index.php;

            location / {
                try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php\$is_args\$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location = /favicon.ico { 
                log_not_found off; 
                access_log off; 
            
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                allow all;
            }

            location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
              expires max;
              log_not_found off;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
            }

        }

    runcmd: 
      - mkdir -p /data/nfs/wordpress
      - mount -t nfs ${wordpress_storage_account_name}.file.core.windows.net:/${wordpress_storage_account_name}/${client_tag}wpstorageshare${environment_prefix} /data/nfs -o vers=4,minorversion=1,sec=sys
      - wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -P /data/nfs/wordpress
      - tar xzvf /data/nfs/wordpress/latest.tar.gz -C /data/nfs/wordpress --strip-components=1
      - cp /tmp/wp-config.php /data/nfs/wordpress/wp-config.php
      - cp /tmp/wordpress.conf  /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress.conf
      - ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress.conf .
      - chown -R www-data:www-data /data/nfs/wordpress
      - rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
      - rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
      - printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
      - systemctl daemon-reload
      - systemctl restart nginx
```

Note: the above cloud-init file is configured to unzip and place WordPress nginx config files in a directory mounted to an Azure Storage account configured to be an NFS.

Some things I have tried to fix it are below:

- updating the "location /" block syntax was incorrect (no change)
- Checked the configuration syntax using `sudo nginx -t` (returned OK)
- tried changing port nginx server is listening to (no change)
- explored serial log for possible errors while configuring VM (no errors)
- ran 'sudo systemctl status nginx' to check for server errors (status was RUNNING)

My expectations were that wordpress setup would show up when access the public ip on the application gateway for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question. The answer is to have the symlink being created in the root directory under a sites-enabled directory.
For this example in particular that looks like:\

```bash
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress.conf /data/nfs/wordpress/sites-enabled/wordpress.conf
```

Note: these questions are specific to deploying wordpress on Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets with an Azure Application Gateway.

Additionally, if you have done this and are still getting 502 errors.
Make sure wordpress is able to establish a database connection. To do this you can login to the server through which ever method you prefer and run `curl localhost:port` to see what nginx is returning.

It is suggested that you go on the server to curl the html response from the server because Application Gateway will return 502 if none of the VM instances are healthy.